# Use Google Maps V3 From Code Behind?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm getting a 404 not found with this url on the geocoding call:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode?output=json&key=MYGOOGLEKEY&sensor=false&address=ARealAddressintheUS

What is wrong here? I've tried it with a key and without.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests), the request url should be of the form:

> Geocoding Requests
> A Geocoding API request must be of the following form:
> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/output?parameters
>
> where output may be either of the following values:
>
> json (recommended) indicates output in JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)
>
> xml indicates output as XML

following that works for me:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=New%20York,%20NY

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you.  So simple but I missed it. This works. You're a star.